# How and where to deploy my Python and BottlePy application

Tags: python, deployment, hosting, bottle

Ok, so I made this application in Bottle that uses the NLTK package. It works fine on my computer which has all neccesary libraries installed, however, I can't get it to work on Google's App Engine. It gives these errors:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getuid'
```

I searched around and think this is a limitation of GAE, so I tried to use Alwaysdata and host my app there. However over there I have the problem that the YAML module is not installed. I tried to install it but access was denied.

```
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yaml': Permission denied
```

So now I am stuck. This is the problem I walk into a lot. It all works fine on my computer, but then I can't get it to work online. Is this because of GAE limitations, alwaysdata limitations? So I guess I am asking where and how could I deploy best?

Is it more easy when I rent my own server and have full access there? Does that work as if it were my own computer and I can install everything?

Let me know if I need to provide more information, I'm pretty clueless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great success running all different types of Python frameworks on WebFaction - http://www.webfaction.com/

Their support is awesome, instant replies to any problems I face. You get SSH access and can install your own modules, virtual-envs etc. You can run sites as a Custom Application listening on a port number, so you can basically run anything.

Here's a thread on how to setup a Bottle app with them: http://community.webfaction.com/questions/3998/how-to-setup-a-python-bottle-application

All that for $8.50/month if you pay a year upfront. http://www.webfaction.com/services/hosting

I can't recommend them enough.

Edit: Thought it wise to mention, I've written apps that use the NLTK and they've run on WebFaction with no troubles.

Comment: thanks so much, have bought their plan and got NLTK to work. Have tried is at so many hosts before, finally it works now! Support was quick indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I realise that you've already found an answer, but for other people looking for Python bottle hosting. [PythonAnywhere has a quickstart option for deploying and hosting bottle](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) apps now.

This is a three or four click wizard process that will have a barebones bottle application running in a 10 seconds. Letting you then build from there.

Comment: Hey, don't forget to plug the free plan! (said Hansel's colleague)